# how to create language dictionaries

Tags: asp.net, localization

I'm building a web app that's going to support multiple languages. For the moment, the words are hard-coded in English in the HTML and javascript. I want to use objects that contains the English word as the key and the word to be displayed as the value and have this dictionary object populate the page at runtime. But my question is not about client-side issues.

What's the best way to store and maintain this dictionary on the server. So far, I thought of a database table with columns for the English word and rows for the values to be displayed. I would then load an entire row in an anonymous type that I'd serialize in json and send the client. I think it'd work but I'm wondering if that's the best way to do it so that the dictionary will be easy to maintain.

If you've had some experience dealing with internationalization then please let me know if you have some suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using resource files?

Comment: no, I didn't know what these are; is there a link you particularly recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Resouce files for multiple language support for asp.net web. It is THE BEST method to use for multiple language support in asp.net. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx